# iphone numberOfSectionsInTableView message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, dealloc

I have the a crash problem-> ([AGIPCAssetsController numberOfSectionsInTableView:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x1976d7b0)
  , and it sometimes happens, but sometimes doesn't happen.
    So, I have no idea how to solve it. It seems I did something wrong in tableview memory management.
    I tested in iOS7/iOS7.1 iphone4. I didn't test much about other version/phones.
    Here's my code.

```
@interface AGIPCAssetsController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, 
UITableViewDelegate, AGIPCGridItemDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate >{
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

I set tableview property to retain, but it call numberOfSectionsInTableView after dealloc.
 Here're my questions.
 1. any idea to solve it?
 2. any idea to workaround. such as call [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.5]; in the beginning of dealloc , to keep object alive.

Comment: Well, definitely don't try to slow down `dealloc`...

Comment: The problem is the table view is trying to reload its data after its datasource has been deallocated.  Find out why this is happening.

Comment: Has the UITableView been removed from the superview? Are there any other places where the tableview may have been retained? Slowing down dealloc will only delay the inevitable.

Comment: In the `dealloc` method of this controller, set the table view's `delegate` and `dataSource` properties to `nil`.

Comment: Yes, the viewController is pop, then dealloc is called. tableview's property is retained, and it's IOoutlet, Should I retain it in somewhere? I have no idea where's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set tableView's delegate and dataSource to nil before viewcontroller will be deallocated. For example:

```
_tableView.delegate = nil;
_tableView.dataSource = nil;
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And in most cases, you should use weak attribute for tableView instead of retain which equals to strong in ARC.

Comment: It really prevent from my crash problem. I'm using non-ARC for my project, and I have no idea, this module tableview doesn't have this kind of problem  in my previous code, but it happen in recent days. I'm not sure if I upgrade to iOS 7/7.1 and using SDK 7.1 for xcode. What's the correct design framework for tableview?  Do you have any suggested example? I didn't see example for setting tableView.dataSource=nil before popViewController, so I'm not sure if it has some side-effect.